# How to you make a string variable, that goes by it's number? For example uppercase A is 65. ASCII Charts

Tags: javascript, ascii

I want to have it so the user is prompted to enter the second string, that will sort lower alphabetically than the first string. I don't understand how to make a string a number? Do I even need to do that?

```js
function SortStringAlphabetically() {
  // Declare variables
  var stringOne = "";
  var stringTwo = "";
  var output;
  

  // Get input from user
  stringOne = prompt("Please enter a string");
  stringTwo = prompt("Please enter enter a string that will sort lower alphabetically than the first string.");

  // Convert input strings to numbers
  stringOne = Number(stringOne);
  stringTwo = Number(stringTwo);

  if ( stringTwo > stringOne) {
    output = "very good" + stringOne + "sorts lower than" + stringTwo + ".";
  } else {
    output = stringOne + "sorts higher than" + stringTwo + "try again";
  }

  document.write(output);
}

// Run the program
SortStringAlphabetically();
// END OF YOUR CODE
```

Comment: Not sure why you converted to Number.  You don't need to.  After the prompts, just try `if (stringTwo < stringOne)`.  e.g.  `'apple' < 'ball'` is `true`.  Also want to point out that your logic and reward string are backwards from the prompt string.  You're prompting `stringTwo` to be something that will sort lower, but then remarking positively that `stringOne` sorts lower than `stringTwo`.

Comment: You can get character code of one character with [String.charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)